# c# Make several statements without losing the processor

Tags: c#, multithreading, communication

I'm wondering if there is a way in C# to ensure two or more following statements would be executed in one shot without losing the prosesor in the middle?
Lets say I need those two statements to be executed as one.
Is there a way to do that in C# windows 7?

```
{
    m_oComManager.fWrite(l_bReadRequest);            
    s_oWaitForMsgRes.fDown();
}
```

Comment: In what way do you mean "losing the processor" ?

Comment: Not really. Please explain the context - why would this be desirable?

Comment: @BugFinder I think he means the os scheduler handing the processor to another process happening midway between 2 statements.

Comment: I seems like you might be trying to manage access to resources from multiple threads. You could introduce a lock around the code that is accessing the resource to ensure no other thread can enter the block until the current thread exits the lock.

Comment: In this increasingly multi-core world, even if you do manage to avoid "losing the processor" there can easily be *other* code running at the same time. Would that be an issue to you?

Comment: Most likely an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and thread synchronization plays a part in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows is a preemptive OS and you can't control when it chooses to give a chance to another thread. So no — not in C# not in assembler not even in machine codes you can execute 2 statements without a chance for these statements to be executed in different time slices allocated by the OS.

Still I believe your problem is different from what you are asking and you don't need 2 statements to execute at the same quantum.

Answer (score 0):

Lock around them:

```
lock (m_oComManager)
{
    m_oComManager.fWrite(l_bReadRequest);            
    s_oWaitForMsgRes.fDown();
}
```

Although you'd need to introduce the same lock anywhere else where it might clash.

Also you may be solving the wrong problem; but can't tell without more context.

Comment: That doesn't guarantee the statements will be executed without a context switch happening. But synchronization in one form or another is most likely what he/she needs.

Comment: While correct; an answer that sets thread affinity for one core; then changes the thread affinity for every process to ignore that core would probably be an answer to the wrong problem

Answer (score 0):

You said: "statements would be executed in one shot", I guess you want to execute statements concurrently? If so, you can use Task Parallelism (from .NET 4.0 or higher).

Example:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => DoSomeWork(), () => DoSomeOtherWork());
```

this will make DoSomeWork and DoSomeOtherWork run concurrently.

[Task Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.100).aspx)